# How to rename certain JSON Object attribute to display it in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, dynatable

If I have a list of objects acquired from a database

```
[{ "id":0 ,"name":"John", "lastname":"Shell" },{ "id":1,...];
```

which results in (dynatable plugin):

```
 data : JSON.stringify(data)
 success: function(data,status){ 
          $('#table').dynatable({
            dataset:{
              records:data
            }
          })
        }
```

but I don't want to show the *id* on 'th' when generating a table in the html, instead I want to rename it to *securityNumber* without changing the actual JSON

```
      <table id="tabela">
        <thead>
           <th>id</th>
           <th>name<th>
           <th>last_name<th>
        </thead>
      </table>
```

I can't just replace id  because the plugin identifies the columns name through the attribute of the JSON Object

I've tryed different plugins, i'm using dynatable (already searched at the documentation) but I am open to another solution.

How do I proceed ?

Comment: Check the documentation of the `dynatable` plugin, I'll bet it provides a way for you to specify the column names that differ from the JSON properties.

Comment: Here it is: [Converting attribute names](https://www.dynatable.com/#converting-attribute-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom formatting method on `textTransform` and write up the mappings for the column names there. Check the docs [here](https://www.dynatable.com/#converting-attribute-names).

An example of such a method might be

```
dynatable.utility.textTransform.customColumnName = function(text) {
  if (text) === 'id' return 'security_number'
  return text
}
```

Alternatively, you can transform the array with `Array.map` without changing the source JSON, for example:

```
...
records: data.map((item) => {
  return {
    security_number: item.id,
    name: item.name,
    last_name: item.last_name
  }
}),
...
```